# SlidingMenu from jfeinstein10 without ActionBarSherlock example

Tags: android, android-actionbar, slidingmenu

The last few days I've been searching for examples on how to make a sliding menu. I've found many ways and decided that jfeinstein10's solution should work best. But the example he has, uses ActionBarSherlock which I don't want, and is also too complicated for me.

I tried to find a simple example with android's action Bar but couldn't find one. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to extend `SherlockActivity`, and create a **`menu.xml`** wich is your menu layout.

Then just add those few lines in your `onCreate` method.

```
menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
```

That what i'm using right now and works perfectly.

If you don't want ActionBar, just hide it like this :

```
ActionBar myBar = getActionBar();
myBar.hide();
```

Comment: Tried that but I get errors on these 3 lines:
  
`menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);`  
shadow_width, shadow and slidingmenu_offset cannot be resolved or they are not a field.

Comment: Thats normal if you didn't import those files. Download the github project of slidingmenu and retrieve those file in the package download. Then drag and drop them into your own project.

Comment: I use it as it is described on the website of SlidingMenu and I do extend only 'Activity' and it works perfect.