# drawer layout with sliding action bar like facebook

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I am making an app. I need to implement a drawer layout. I had done that part but now i have to slide action bar while opening drawer layout like face Book. Please give me some solution.

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use external library for sliding menu. Here it is like for library and source example

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Hope you like it

Comment: acually when i had download this. it need abs library.. what is that??

Comment: first you download full zip file from link. link contains example and library. after that add that library in your android project. and that abs mean project need to add ActionBarSherlock library.

Comment: for ignore abs library error refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557900/slidingmenu-from-jfeinstein10-without-actionbarsherlock-example

Comment: actually it needs two library. and there is only one library available. So that's the problem. you can check that. please help me

Comment: @Mansi-can you give me complete code. if u have. please give me. my email id is. anand.it402@gmail.com

Comment: as I said you have to use abs means ActionBarSherlock library. if you don't want to use remove all ActionBarSherlock library code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49401/discussion-between-anandroid-and-mansi)