# Auto close sliding menu onchild click

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu, jfeinstein

I have imported correctly the sliding menu library by jfeinstein and all is working except one thing. When I click on the "net" element in the sliding menu it opens the "net" fragment but it doesn't close the menu as it should does automatically.

SlidingMenu

```
 public class SlidingMenuFragment extends Fragment implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener {
private SlidingMenu slidingMenu ;
private ExpandableListView sectionListView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    List<Section> sectionList = createMenu();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidingmenu_fragment, container, false);
    this.sectionListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.slidingmenu_view);
    this.sectionListView.setGroupIndicator(null);
    SectionListAdapter sectionListAdapter = new SectionListAdapter(this.getActivity(), sectionList);
    this.sectionListView.setAdapter(sectionListAdapter); 

    this.sectionListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            return true;
          }
        });

    this.sectionListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);

    int count = sectionListAdapter.getGroupCount();
    for (int position = 0; position < count; position++) {
        this.sectionListView.expandGroup(position);
    }

    return view;
}

private List<Section> createMenu() {
    List<Section> sectionList = new ArrayList<Section>();

    Section oDemoSection = new Section("Demos");
    oDemoSection.addSectionItem(101,"Test", "lol");
    oDemoSection.addSectionItem(102, "Airport (AsyncTask)", "lol");

    Section oGeneralSection = new Section("General");
    oGeneralSection.addSectionItem(201, "Settings", "lol");
    oGeneralSection.addSectionItem(202, "Rate this app", "lol");
    oGeneralSection.addSectionItem(203, "Eula", "lol");
    oGeneralSection.addSectionItem(204, "Quit", "lol");

    sectionList.add(oDemoSection);
    sectionList.add(oGeneralSection);
    return sectionList;
}

@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    Fragment fragment=null;

    switch ((int)id) {

    case 101:
        fragment = new Net();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        break;
    case 102:
        //TODO
        break;
    case 201:
        //TODO
        break;
    case 202:
        //TODO
        break;
    case 203:
        //TODO
        break;
    case 204:
        //TODO
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

---

MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private SlidingMenu slidingMenu ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    slidingMenu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_shadow_width);
    slidingMenu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.slidingmenu_shadow);
    slidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slidingmenu);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if ( slidingMenu.isMenuShowing()) {
        slidingMenu.toggle();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        slidingMenu.toggle();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        this.slidingMenu.toggle();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


        }
}
```

Comment: use sliding menu's toggle

Comment: Please be more specific. I tried slidingMenu.toggle(); after .commit(); but it makes app crashing.

Comment: how u r initializing the sliding menu and how u r accessing.? u haven't given the code that how u initialized and used.

Comment: Ok I have updated the thread with the mainactivity, please let me know

Comment: in which place it is not working?

Comment: When I click on "net" button in the sliding menu it opens the related fragment but it doesn't autoclose the menu. So I think here:  case 101:
        fragment = new Net();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        break;

Comment: if I add slidingMenu.toggle() (to autotoggle the sliding menu) when I click on "test" element I have java null exception and the app crashes. please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17558925/1937802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all  write `MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity`. Change also in your MainActivity

```
> private SlidingMenu slidingMenu
```

with

```
public static SlidingMenu slidingMenu
```

now inside your MainActivity you can call toggle() instead of this.slidingMenu.toggle() and whenever you want to use it inside a Fragment you can write:

```
> MainActivity.slideMenu.toggle()
```

of course you can use every other method of your static SlidingMenu by the same way.

Comment: To close, first check if menu is showing

if(slidingMenu.isMenuShowing())
            slidingMenu.toggle();